# How do I make Firefox save form data for websites that specifically disallow it?

Tags: firefox

There are certain websites (ebanking, universities, etc.) that do not allow the browser to save form data as a security precaution.

Please recommend a good Firefox plugin or a setting that will allow me to store username/password fields on those sites, so I don't have to enter it every time.

Comment: Also please note that there's a reason why e.g. banking sites disable form saving in browsers. malware can potentially send all saved formdata to third parties.

Comment: @anttir True, but this information is not enough information on its own for potential criminals if your banking provider uses transaction numbers. Don't know why more banks (especially those in the US) don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around this restriction using the [LastPass](http://www.lastpass.com) password manager and it's associated Firefox Plugin. It's able to save log-in information from websites that FireFox alone would not. It'll also save other form-fill items like address, phone number, etc, if you wish, as well as generate and save very secure passwords for you, semi-automatically. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/form-history-control), it can store form fields on any site.

I use it frequently and it helps a lot with remembering things, but you need to configure it in a way to work it with everything:

[image]
(Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijuZY.png) for a full-size version.)

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox Plugin [Web-Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) provides an option to (re)enable autocompletition for disabled form fields. Once installed, being on the website that obviously has autocompletition disabled, on the Web Developer Toolbar go to Menu Forms, enable autocompletition. Then fill in the form, and it will ask you to save it like a normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I found the solution in a very light way by using a bookmarklet.

Open a dummy bookmark and replace the URL with this code.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20ca,cea,cs,df,dfe,i,j,x,y;function%20n(i,what){return%20i+"%20"+what+((i==1)?"":"s")}ca=cea=cs=0;df=document.forms;for(i=0;i<df.length;++i){x=df[i];dfe=x.elements;if(x.onsubmit){x.onsubmit="";++cs;}if(x.attributes["autocomplete"]){x.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++ca;}for(j=0;j<dfe.length;++j){y=dfe[j];if(y.attributes["autocomplete"]){y.attributes["autocomplete"].value="on";++cea;}}}alert("Removed%20autocomplete=off%20from%20"+n(ca,"form")+"%20and%20from%20"+n(cea,"form%20element")+",%20and%20removed%20onsubmit%20from%20"+n(cs,"form")+".%20After%20you%20type%20your%20password%20and%20submit%20the%20form,%20the%20browser%20will%20offer%20to%20remember%20your%20password.")})();
```

[image]

I don't remember where I found it.

Click this bookmark just before clicking **Submit** on the **Login** form. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I used Saved Password Editor: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/